# systemd ExecStopPost not running if ExecStartPre fails?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I've gone over the documentation for `systemd` here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html.

It states in the `ExecStartPre=,ExecStartPost=` section

> Note that if any of the commands specified in ExecStartPre=,
>   ExecStart=, or ExecStartPost= fail (and are not prefixed with "-", see
>   above) or time out before the service is fully up, execution continues
>   with commands specified in ExecStopPost=, the commands in ExecStop=
>   are skipped

I have an `ExecStartPre` rule being

`ExecStartPre=/bin/false`

In `ExecStopPost` I have an `/bin/echo "I'm at ExecStopPost"`.

The service looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "I'm at ExecStartPre"
ExecStartPre=/bin/false
ExecStart=/bin/echo "Running Test"
ExecStopPost=/bin/echo "I'm at ExecStopPost"
```

When it runs and fails, I never see it. Output from syslog looks like

> Jun 15 20:48:01 ip-10-0-0-246 echo[8687]: I'm at ExecStartPre
>
> Jun 15 20:48:01 ip-10-0-0-246 systemd[1]: test.service: Control
>   process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> Jun 15 20:48:01 ip-10-0-0-246 systemd[1]: Failed to start test.
>
> Jun 15 20:48:01 ip-10-0-0-246 systemd[1]: test.service.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> Jun 15 20:48:01 ip-10-0-0-246 systemd[1]: test.service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I never see my echo.

`journalctl -u test.service` of course also has this as it's entry.

Do I need to configure this slightly differently? Or do I need to use `OnFailure`?

I need to be able to restart a `Conflicts=` on success or failure cases. This will be used in oneshot services triggered by timers.

Oh and this is running on 16.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `oneshot` services don't call `ExecStopPost` on failure. This link discusses it https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1353039.

The relevant post being

> ExecStopPost is executed only when unit transitions from running state
>   (even when unit is killed) or when Main PID exits successfully while
>   in activating state and service is not of forking type.
>
> Difference is that in case of oneshot service while configured
>   ExecStart actions are executing, service is still in activating state
>   and not running. However in case of simple service, systemd
>   immediately transitions service to running state, systemctl doesn't
>   block and exit 0 is returned even when ExecStart fails (i.e.
>   ExecStart=/bin/false). Thus oneshot service must exit cleanly in order
>   for ExecStopPost to be called. AFAICT, option RemainAfterExit doesn't
>   have an impact on ExecStopPost.

The solution ended up being adding an `OnFailure` to invoke the necessary items which would have been called in `ExecStopPost`